# Pass JVM debug parameters to Spring JarLauncher

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to pass *debug* parameters when calling [JarLauncher.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.java) using this command line?

`java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`?

Comment: *when running command like java*, well pass any arguments you want. `java -XX... -D..`

Comment: Minor formatting to make it easier to read the question

Answer (score 2):

This command works:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005 org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Debug arguments must appear before the class name.

Comment: In case anyone just copies this string, note: the above is for *older* Java versions (<5). For newer Java versions (9+), use `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`.